# Bug on PDF@StableDistribution when beta is less than -0.995?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I see a problem with `PDF@StableDistribution` when beta is less than `-0.995`, Mathematica 10.0 and 11.0 64 bit for Windows, try for example:

```
Plot[PDF[StableDistribution[0, 1.88, -0.995, 0., 0.1], x], {x, -6 , -4},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You'll see a discontinuity that should not exist, how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use bug tag unless it is confirmed by community or WRI Support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at it is that it has to do with round-off (and possibly underflow, I suppose).  This can be addressed by increasing the working precision (and the precision of the parameters):

```
Plot[PDF[StableDistribution[0, 1.88`32, -0.995`32, 0, 0.1`32], 
  x], {x, -6, -4}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

This is just an extended comment.  As there is no closed-form formula for a stable distribution (except for certain special combinations of parameters) numerical methods are used to estimate the density.  All such algorithms don't always work well in the tail regions.

To put your issue in perspective consider extending the plot range to `{-6,1}`:

```
Show[
  Plot[PDF[StableDistribution[0, 1.88, -0.995, 0., 0.1], x], {x, -6, 1},
    PlotRange -> All],
  ListPlot[{{-6, 0}, {-4, 0}}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.02], 
    Joined -> True, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
]
```

[image: PDF of stable distribution]

The highlighted portion in the lower left of the figure is the range for your original figure.  If you really need great accuracy in the tail regions, you should report this issue directly to Wolfram, Inc.